# Why do we HAVE to test the first and second derivative to determine the nature of a stationary point?

Tags: calculus

Classically, students are taught two ways of determining the nature of a stationary point of some curve $y=f(x)$.

The first is to use a table of values and to test say $x=0.9$, $x=1$ and $x=1.1$ if the stationary point is at $x=1$. These values are input into the gradient function to determine the slopes before and after the stationary point.

The second is to substitute $x=1$ directly into the second derivative and examining the sign of the resultant number.

My question is, why is it necessary to use these methods? Why can we not simply substitute these values into our original function to observe the behaviour of the curve around that stationary point, and thus the nature of it?

Comment: Try to apply your proposed method to the function $f(x)=x^2\sin\left({1\over x}\right)$ in a neighborhood of $x=0$.

Comment: The short answer is curves can be "really wobbly" about some point, requiring "too many test points" to have that be practical.

Comment: I mean, even if we can surely get some insight by numerical experiment, the behaviour of a function can be complex even at arbitrarily small scale. Hence the need for theoretical tools that can handle those situations.

Comment: I understand how the second derivative can be preferable in that case. Naturally, introducing a sinusoid can cause issues. Do you have a similar example which does not include the trigonometric functions?

Comment: I think you need to consider the more powerful first derivative test also.

Answer (score 3):

Your first approach, using values, can be fooled if there is structure to the curve at a smaller scale.  If I define $f(x)=(x-0.99)^2(x-1.01)^2$ it has a stationary point at $x=1$.  Looking at the values at $x=0.9, 1.1$ one would conclude that $x=1$ is a local minimum, but it is not.  The second derivative test will get it right.

I'm not sure what you mean by "substitute these values into our original function to observe the behaviour of the curve".  What would you do in this case?

Comment: I should have clarified. I chose 0.9 and 1.1 randomly to demonstrate that the choice for substitutions will be sufficiently close to the stationary point such that there wouldn't exist stationary points in between our testing values. 

What I meant by that was to simply substitute in the x values around the stationary point to see whether it 'bounces off' or if it 'continues on' ie: suggesting a turning point or an inflexion point respectively. Similarly, the choices for X would be such that the only stationary point between those choices is the one we intend to test.

Comment: Yes, that will work fine if you can look at the function and know the scale of the structure.  In my example it is easy to see that using $0.999$ and $1.001$ will work nicely.  For more complicated functions it may not be so obvious.  It is not the sine function in $\sin (\frac 1x)$, it is the conjunction of the sine and the increasing (as you near $x=0$) frequency.  There is no scale that you can use.  We could use any other oscillating function besides the sine.